# Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it}) dtds > 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, polynomials

This problem is adapted from 2013 Putnam A6. It's restated here for convenience.

> For any nonempty finite set of pairs of integers $S$, let $f(x,y) = \sum_{(a,b)\in S} x^a y^b.$ Let $g(x,y) = \sum_{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2} w(a,b) x^a y^b$, where $w(a,b)$ is defined by the following table where the value of $w(a,b)$ is in the cell corresponding to $(a,b)$:
>
> $\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
> \hline
> a\backslash b & -2& -1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\\hline
> -2 &-1 & -2 & 2 & -2 & -1 \\ \hline
> -1 & -2 & 4 & -4 & 4 & -2\\ \hline
> 0& 2 & -4 & 12&-4 &2\\ \hline
> 1 &-2& 4& -4  & 4& -2\\ \hline
> 2 & -1 & -2 &2 & -2& -1\\ \hline
> \end{array}$
>
> Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it}) dtds > 0.$

Note that $g(e^{is}, e^{it}) = 16G(\cos s, \cos t)$ where $G(z,w) = zw + z^2 + w^2 - zw^2 - z^2 w - z^2 w^2$. Also one can show $G(z,w)$ is nonnegative  on $[-1,1]^2$ and equal to zero iff $(z,w)\in \{(1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1),(0,0)\}$ by noting that for $zw\ge 0, G(z,w) = zw(1-zw) + (1-w)z^2 + w^2(1-z)$ and for $zw\leq 0, G(z,w) = (z+w)^2-zw(1+z)(1+w).$

However, it's possible that $f(x,y)$ may have uncountably many zeroes, and so it's not clear that $|f(e^{is}, e^{it})|^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})$ is nonzero on a set of nonzero measure.

> For completeness, here's the verification of the claim that $g(e^{is}, e^{it}) = 16G(\cos s, \cos t).$

$\begin{align}g(e^{is}, e^{it}) &= (e^{is})^{-2}(-(e^{it})^{-2} -2(e^{it})^{-1} + 2 - 2(e^{it}) - (e^{it})^2) + (e^{is})^{-1}(-2(e^{it})^{-2} +4(e^{it})^{-1} - 4 + 4(e^{it}) -2(e^{it})^2) + (2(e^{it})^{-2} - 4(e^{it})^{-1} + 12 - 4(e^{it})+2(e^{it})^2) + (e^{is})(-2(e^{it})^{-2} + 4(e^{it})^{-1} - 4 + 4(e^{it}) -2(e^{it})^2) + (e^{is})^2(-(e^{it})^{-2} - 2(e^{it})^{-1}+2 - 2(e^{it}) -(e^{it})^{-1})\end{align} $

We have $\cos s = \dfrac{e^{is} + e^{-is}}2, \cos t = \dfrac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}2.$ Substituting these values into $16G(\cos s, \cos t)$ gives $\begin{align}G(\cos s, \cos t) &= 4((e^{is} + e^{-is})(e^{it}+e^{-it}) + (e^{is} + e^{-is})^2 + \\
&(e^{it}+e^{-it})^2 - 1/2 (e^{is}+e^{-is})(e^{it}+e^{-it})^2 - 1/2(e^{is}+e^{-is})^2 (e^{it}+e^{-it}) - 1/4(e^{is}+e^{-is})^2 (e^{it}+e^{-it})^2)\\
&=4(e^{is}(e^{it}+e^{-it}) + e^{-is}(e^{it}+e^{-it}) + e^{2is} + 2 + e^{-2is} + (e^{2it} + 2+e^{-2it})) \\
&-2(e^{is}(e^{2it} + 2+e^{-2it}) + e^{-is}(e^{2it} + 2+e^{-2it}) +e^{2is}(e^{it}+e^{-it}) + (2e^{it} + 2e^{-it})+e^{-2is}(e^{it}+e^{-it}))\\
&-(e^{2is}(e^{2it}+2+e^{-2it}) +  2(e^{2it}+2+e^{-2it}) + e^{-2is}(e^{2it}+2+e^{-2it}))\\
&= e^{-2is}(4-2e^{it}-2e^{-it}-e^{2it}-2-e^{-2it}) +e^{-is}(4e^{it}+4e^{-it}-2e^{2it}-4-2e^{-2it}) \\
&+ (8+4e^{2it} + 8 + 4e^{-2it}-4e^{it}-4e^{-it}-2e^{2it}-4-2e^{-2it}) \\
&+ e^{is}(4e^{it}+4e^{-it}-2e^{2it}-4-2e^{-2it})+ e^{2is}(4-2e^{it}-2e^{-it}-e^{2it}-2-e^{-2it})\\
&= g(e^{is}, e^{it})\end{align}$

> Also below are some notes about the putnam problem, which asks to show that $A(S) := \sum_{s,s'\in S} w(s-s')$ is positive for any $\emptyset\neq S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$. Note that $h(e^{is}, e^{it}) = f(e^{is} ,e^{it})f(e^{-is}, e^{-it}) g(e^{is}, e^{it}) = |f(e^{is}, e^{it})|^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})$ (because for any multivariate polynomial $f(x_1,\cdots, x_n),$ we have that by conjugate properties and (double) induction on n and the degree of f, $f(\overline{x_1},\cdots, \overline{x_n}) = \overline{f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)}$). Also, $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} h(e^{is}, e^{it}) dtds$ equals $(2\pi)^2 A(S)$ because all nonconstant factors cancel; for any $(a,b)\neq (0,0), \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{isa} e^{itb} dt ds = 0$. Finally, to verify that $A(S)$ is indeed the constant coefficient of the Laurent polynomial $h(x,y)=f(x,y)f(x^{-1},y^{-1}) g(x,y),$ we can just use the standard approach for finding the constant coefficient of a multivariate polynomial. The coefficient of $x^a y^b$ in a two-variable product of Laurent polynomials $p(x,y)=f(x,y)g(x,y)$ equals $\sum_{(i_1,j_1), (i_2,j_2)\in \mathbb{Z}^2, i_1 + i_2 = a, j_1 + j_2 = b}[x^{i_1} y^{j_1}]f(x,y) [x^{i_2}y^{j_2}]g(x,y),$ which is well-defined since f and g have finitely many nonzero coefficients. For a real number $r$ and set $S$ let $rS := \{rs : s\in S\}.$ Hence for the particular instance, we have that the constant coefficient of $h(x,y)$ equals

$\begin{align}&\sum_{(i_1,j_1), (i_2,j_2)\in \mathbb{Z}^2, i_1 + i_2 = 0, j_1 + j_2 = 0}[x^{i_1} y^{j_1}]f(x,y) [x^{-i_1}y^{-j_1}](f(x^{-1}, y^{-1}) g(x,y)) \\
&=  \sum_{(i_1,j_1)\in S}[x^{i_1} y^{j_1}]f(x,y) \sum_{(i_2, j_2)\in (-S)}[x^{i_2}y^{j_2}](f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})) [x^{-i_1-i_2}y^{-j_1-j_2}]g(x,y)\\
&= \sum_{(i_1,j_1)\in S} \sum_{(i_2, j_2)\in (-S)} [x^{-i_1-i_2}y^{-j_1-j_2}]g(x,y)\\
&= \sum_{s, s' \in S} w(s-s')\quad \text{ (by setting } (i_1,j_1) = s', (-i_2,-j_2)=s\end{align}$

Comment: there is something wrong with your integral as for example if $w(0,0)=-1, w(a,b)=0$ otherwise, then $g=-1$ and the integral is negative

Comment: @Conrad or there are more conditions on $g$ than what is stated. But yes, there is an issue.

Comment: Assuming you mean to ask your question while specifying before hand that $g = 16G(\cos s, \cos t) $ where $G$ is as you've written.

Comment: @DionelJaime the problem has been fixed. For reference, this is 2013 putnam A6.

Comment: See [this post on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h566367p3316669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is finite, there is a number $m>1$ such that $|a|<m$ and $|b|<m$ for all $(a,b)\in S$.

Suppose $s, t\in (0,\frac{\pi}{8m})$.
For all $(a,b)\in S$, we have $-\frac\pi4<sa+tb<\frac\pi4$

$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad\ \Re(f(e^{is}, e^{it}))=\Re\left(\sum_{(a,b)\in S} e^{isa} e^{itb}\right)=\Re\left(\sum_{(a,b)\in S} e^{isa+itb}\right)\\
&=\sum_{(a,b)\in S} \Re(e^{isa+itb})=\sum_{(a,b)\in S}\cos(sa+tb)\gt\sum_{(a,b)\in S}\frac{\sqrt2}2=\frac{\sqrt2\,|S|}2,\\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\Re(\cdots)$ is the real part of a complex number, $|S|$ is the number of elements in $S$.
Hence $|f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |\ge\Re(f(e^{is}, e^{it}))>\frac{\sqrt2\,|S|}2.$

As proved in the question, $g(e^{is}, e^{it}) > 0$ if $s,t$ are real numbers in $(0, \pi)$ (so that $\cos s, \cos t\not\in \{1,-1\}$).

So, $|f(e^{is}, e^{it})|^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})>0$ for $(s, t)\in (0,\frac{\pi}{8m})^2$, a set of nonzero measure. Since $|f(e^{is}, e^{it})|^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})$ is continuous, . Hence, $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{8m}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8m}} |f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})\, dtds > 0.$$
Since $|f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})\ge0$, we have
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{is}, e^{it}) |^2 g(e^{is}, e^{it})\, dtds > 0.$$